# C# DataSet validation from XML schema

Tags: c#, validation, datatable, dataset, xsd

I have a xml schema. I want to populate a DataSet and validate it using this schema.

```cs
DataSet package = new DataSet();
StringReader schemaResourceReader = new StringReader(PackageValidationLibrary.Properties.Resources.myPackage);
package.ReadXmlSchema(schemaResourceReader);


package.Tables["Table1"].Rows.Add(packageDetail.date,packageDetail.code,packageDetail.amount,packageDetail.place,"0");
package.Tables["Table2"].Rows.Add("0","0");
foreach (Cek data in recordList){
    package.Tables["Table3"].Rows.Add(data.Serial, data.Code, data.Branch, data.ValidityDate, "0");
}
```

Using the code above I can load data but I cannot validate it although dataset imports the schema.

I tried to get xml string using package.GetXml() method and reload the xml again. Then I got exceptions.

How can I validate this table? Thanks.

---

**EDIT**
As I understand from answers and comments it is not possible to validate while populating the dataset. Then I read the xml from dataset and loaded it with the configuration given below.

```cs
_schema = XmlSchema.Read(new StringReader(PackageValidationLibrary.Properties.Resources.TakasPaketi), new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler));
                XmlReaderSettings _settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
                _settings.Schemas.Add(_schema);
                _settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
                XmlReader vreader = XmlReader.Create(stream, _settings);
```

Comment: In general, reading the XML Schema sets up the allowances for the dataSet, table structure and the like.  It then live validates itself.  You wont be allowed to add anything that wont match the schema, so a Validated table is an automatic assumption, if the schema is set up correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will do it:

```
    // First, read in the XML schema
    DataSet MyDataSet = new DataSet();
    MyDataSet.ReadXmlSchema(@"C:\YourSchema.xsd");


    // Now, read in the XML file (it is validated 
    // against the schema when it is read in).
    MyDataSet.ReadXml(@"C:\YourFile.xml");
```

If you edit the data xml file to not match the schema, an exception will be thrown when the xml file is read.

So in your case you may have to export the dataset to an xml string and then read it back in.  You say you are getting exceptions when you do this....what exceptions?   Maybe the data isn't valid for the schema you have.

Comment: Note that this model will only validate those xml schema constraints that affect the ability to create a valid data set.  For example, it will validate that "five" is not a valid xs:integer value.  However, if you have something like an enumeration restriction on a string (xs:enumeration), it does not validate that string values in the xml file actually match one of the identified possible values for the enumeration.